# Laravel updating Model Fails because of relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a situation where I fetch a model in Laravel. Something like this:

```
$user = User::with('subscription')->where('id', '=', 123)->first();
```

If I then later try and do something like this:

```
$user->firstname = 'John';
$user->save();
```

I get an SQL error because it says that there is no DB field called "subscription" It seems like the relationship is being treated as a DB field when saving. Is that right? Am I mean to

```
unset($user->subscription)
```

before saving?

Is it not possible to update a model if there is a relationship attached? Does it have to be removed before saving?

Comment: try dd($user) before save() and see if the relationship exists

Comment: The relationship does exist.

Comment: You have to add a method to your model called "subscription"

Comment: I have the method there, that is how I eager load the relationship. The problem is when I try and save the user model and the subscription model is still attached as a relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was causing this. In a previous place in my code I was trying to update the relationship. Accidentally I was assigning the subscription as an attribute to my user object. This was not a Laravel issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

create new user object

```
$user = new User;
$user->firstname = 'John';
$user->save();
```

Comment: But the whole point is that I fetched the user from the DB with a relationship attached. I understand how to update a model without an attached relationship.

Comment: I would expect that the model would update without any problem. It seems I am getting an SQL error because it is treating the relationship object as a DB field.

Comment: I fetched the model with a relationship (eager loaded) then I try and update the model.

Comment: I wrote above, I don't create a new User, I fetched a user from the DB with a subscription object attached as a relationship.

Comment: using which field you update the record? `User::where('condition')->update($user);`

Comment: so I should something like `$user->update(['firstname' => 'John']);` instead of save()?

Comment: Seems to create the same problem. Save doesn't seem to work well if you try to save with a relationship attached to the model.

Answer (score 0):

Same code is working for me. What laravel version are you using?

```
    $psc = Subject::with('group')->where('group_id', 1)->first();

    $psc->group->name = 'PSC';
    $psc->group->save();
    dd($psc->group);

    $psc->name = 'Science';
    $psc->save();
    dd($psc->name);
```

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.5

Comment: When I try to do something like this I get an SQL error that "group" is an unknown column.